# Springboot : Catch Exception if there's %2F in url

Tags: spring-boot

I have my request mapping as this -

```
@RequestMapping(value = {
    "/v1/users/{userId:" + UUID_REGEX + "}/groups")
```

And when I try to do a GET with the below url

```
GET /v1/users/%3C%2Ftitle%3E%3Csecurity_scan_xss_13ed9d28-579e-4b5-sss-035d34%2F%3E/groups
```

I'm getting this response -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        ...
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

**Is there a way to catch this, as I want to send a custom error message for all these scenarios?**

I have tried putting `org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true` in properties file but response remains still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, start by creating a custom exception class that extends `IllegalArgumentException` and then throw this exception where the error occurs. By default, all `IllegalArgumentExceptions` are treated as `Http Bad Request`

Comment: Well I don't see anything in stack trace, and the request never reaches my controller or even any of the filters. Request is right away rejected with 400 bad request text/html page from somewhere in the very initial layer which looks like spring handled right now

Comment: Did you try enabling `DEBUG` in logging level of your application. It should give a good idea why the request is being rejected